# Would crystal-asteroids filled with a gas like iodine be plausible to refract light into making a coloured sky?

Tags: planets, atmosphere, chemistry

So I would like a coloured sky in my world, but I want it to be plausible. I'm not so good at science and the like but I've been doing a lot of research.

If crystal-like asteroids filled with coloured gases were a common sight in my atmosphere, would enough light refract to change the colour of the sky?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding. There are no stupid questions (though there can be questions that are unclear or show a lack of own research), but I fear you may be approaching this from the wrong end. Asteroids don't generally *stay put* above a planet's surface, so any effect from the asteroids themselves would be very short-lived, and they are too small to deliver any significant amount of gases to a planet's atmosphere.

Comment: You might be better off if you [Edit] this to instead ask how you can get a color of the sky as seen from the surface that you'd like, given the type (spectral class and temperature; planet orbital distance may be helpful too) of star your planet is orbiting. That would allow answers that discuss how to achieve your desired goal, rather than focusing on a specific way that you've thought of to reach that goal. Make sure to tell us if you need the planet to be habitable for Earth-like life.

Comment: When you say 'coloured' sky, are you asking for multiple colours or just one colour?  Different atmospheric compositions will have different colourings to them, but a multi coloured sky would be an interesting thing to justify.

Comment: From what I can tell, light through an iodine prism would cause it to be mostly red. Assuming that I'm right, there are other ways to get a red sky, one of which is to have a really thick atmosphere. As Sun light passes through thicker atmosphere the blue light is scattered, leaving the red light behind. this is why the sun rise/set are red, because the light at low angles has to pass through more atmosphere.

Answer (score 2):

if i were going to make up some support for multi-colored sky i would start with the atmospheric particles. Ours are of a size that 400ish nanometer light gets scattered (often referred to as the raleigh effect) but you might posit different particles that scatter different wavelengths..

another way to get there would be to change the vision of those looking up. for instance, its theorized that there exist in the world tetrachromats, or people (with two x chromosomes specifically) who have a fourth type of cone cell in their retinas. theres a great radiolab episode about colors in which one lady who might be a tetrachromat describing all the pinks (and yellows?) she sees in a regular old blue sky.

as for diamonds in the sky, you might theorize some race that is able to extract the core from a still burning red giant where godawful amounts of pressure heat and carbon might very well be forming a giant (larger than planet size) diamond. alien tech is *just* as useful as magic